# How can I get the current user in models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I am trying to add the User column to know which User added the tool in the tools/model.py page

```
tools_name = models.CharField('Tool\'s Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
tools_project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to=~Q(project_status=2), verbose_name='Project\'s Name')
user = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=False)
```

But I want to know how to save the user that created or updated the tool ?

Comment: You don't. Django's models should be defined *request-unaware*. So you do this in the view or form. Normally it is also better to use a `ForeignKey` to the user model.

Comment: You can't do this in Django models, but you can explicitly assign user when creating record - it depends where/how you're creating `Tool` records.

Comment: @Charnel - suppose I am using the admin.site dashboard to create the tools how can I add the user name of the logged in user without showing the field ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Do you think I can do it with signal ? with post_save maybe ?

Comment: @AliEzzeddine: no, signals are even worse. Signals should only be used to hook third party events.

Answer (score 2):

Models are normally *request unaware*, so you should not do this. This is a task that belongs in the view. Furthermore normally you work with a `ForeignKey` or a `OneToOneField` or another relation. This is useful since users might eventually change their (user)name. By storing the username, your database can contain a username that no longer exists or even worse: another user now uses that username and the use got then access to the models of the previous "owner".

Your model thus looks like:

```
from user.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    tools_name = models.CharField('Tool\'s Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
    tools_project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        limit_choices_to=~Q(project_status=2),
        verbose_name='Project\'s Name'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
```

You can work with a `ModelForm` for example and then let the view set the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = MyModelForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

For the `ModelAdmin` you can override the [**`.save_model(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model):

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```